# Highlighting individual countries on a world map

Tags: curated-data, geography

Consider the following list of countries which I would like to highlight on a world map:

```
MyCountries={"Germany","Hungary","Mexico","Austria","Bosnia","Turkey","SouthKorea","China"};
```

From the documentation center [(Country Data > Applications > Application 5)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CountryData.html), I know that

```
Graphics[{If[CountryData[#, "AntarcticNations"], Orange, LightBrown], 
    CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

works for all antarctic nations. I replaced `"AntarcticNations"` by `MyCountries` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the example code, `CountryData[#, "AntarcticNations"]` is a built in predicate that returns `True` or `False`.  You need something similar for your countries.  Perhaps,

```
myCountries={
  "Germany","Hungary","Mexico","Austria",
  "Bosnia","Turkey","SouthKorea","China"};
Graphics[{If[MemberQ[myCountries,#],Orange,LightBrown],
  CountryData[#,"SchematicPolygon"]}& /@ CountryData[]]
```

[image]

Comment: `"Bosnia"` is not recognized, should be `"BosniaHerzegovina"`.

Comment: I'd like to add that `CountryData[#, {"Polygon", "Mollweide"}]` allows to set the projection used for the map.

Answer (score 11):

Alternate approach:

```
Graphics[{
  {Orange, CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"] & /@ MyCountries}, 
  {LightBrown, 
      CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"] & /@ Complement[CountryData[], MyCountries]}
  }]
```

which draws all of "your countries" in one color, and then the rest of the world in another.

Answer (score 7):

*Mathematica 10* introduced new ways to highlight countries on the world map. Examples follow below. There are lots of more examples in the documentation which showcase alternative stylings.

```
myCountries = Map[
   Entity["Country", #] &,
   {"Germany", "Hungary", "Mexico", "Austria", "Turkey", "SouthKorea", "China"}
   ];

GeoListPlot[myCountries, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Map 1]

```
GeoListPlot[myCountries, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Map 2]

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[MapThread[Rule, {myCountries, RandomReal[10, Length@myCountries]}]]
```

[image: Map 3]

```
GeoGraphics[
 {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Orange], Polygon /@ myCountries},
 ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

[image]